# Use VSCode explorer with remote server (using SSH)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I need to code / edit files in a remote server using SSH, and I would like to access it with VSCode.

I'm on Windows 10, using "Git Bash" as integrated terminal in VSCode, which means I can connect to the server using VSCode's terminal.
What I'm missing is a way to open files from the terminal to the editor, and even better - interacting with the files using the explorer.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the May, 2nd 2019 announcement of "[Remote Development with VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2019/05/02/remote-development)", you now officially have:

[**Visual Studio Code Remote - SSH**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh)

[image: https://microsoft.github.io/vscode-remote-release/images/ssh-readme.gif]

> The Remote - SSH extension lets you use any remote machine with a SSH server as your development environment.
>   Since nearly every desktop and server operating system has a SSH server that can be configured, the extension can greatly simplify development and troubleshooting in a wide variety of situations.
>
> You can:
>
> - Develop on the same operating system you deploy to or use larger, faster, or more specialized hardware than your local machine.
> - Quickly swap between different, remote development environments and safely make updates without worrying about impacting your local machine.
> - Access an existing development environment from multiple machines or locations.
> - Debug an application running somewhere else such as a customer site or in the cloud.

---

Q1 2020: [VSCode 1.42](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/55f91327db40eb008d632a7b044b6137eb8e059f/release-notes/v1_42.md#remote-development) improves support for Windows servers, including automatic OS detection.

Comment: Is this safe? I mean, the plugin can push a private ssh key somewhere to the cloud in the background, how could we trust this?

Answer (score 1):

All of the previous answers require installing a package from the VS Code Marketplace. Here is a solution, that won't even require you to install VS Code.

**The Web Based VS Code Editor:** Run VS Code on any machine anywhere and access it in the browser.

All you need to do is, first install **code-server** using:

```
$ curl -fsSL https://code-server.dev/install.sh | sh
```

Start **code-server** using:

```
$ code-server
```

After running this you can log on to https://127.0.0.1:8080 and view the web-based VS code.

To keep the service running in the background, use:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart code-server@$USER
```

You might also want to edit the configurations, for e.g., run it on 0.0.0.0:8080 instead of 127.0.0.1:8080 or to change the password - use:

```
$ nano ~/.config/code-server/config.yaml
```

I have used **nano** as my text editor, feel free to use your preferred text editor.

For in-depth setup and configuration guide: [Setup Guide](https://github.com/cdr/code-server/blob/main/docs/guide.md)

Original GitHub repo for more info: [code-server](https://github.com/cdr/code-server)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? 
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=humy2833.ftp-simple#overview

You need to setup sFtp connection to your server.

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot. This is a university server, and I don't have admin access to it.

Comment: Seriously? I think you never been to code's marketplace. It is for visual studio code, and I use it myself every day! @ErnstErnst

Comment: @galah92 you don't have to have admin access. Just use your ssh credential or key.

Answer (score 0):

Install extensions Code Runner and SSH-FS. Add config into your user setting like this:

```js
"code-runner.runInTerminal":true,
"code-runner.fileDirectoryAsCwd": true,
"code-runner.ignoreSelection": true,
"code-runner.saveFileBeforeRun": true,
"files.eol": "\n",
"sshfs.configs": [
    {
        "label": "label",
        //Must use the root direction "/"
        "root": "/",
        "host": "host",
        "port": port,
        "username": "name",
        "password": "password"
        "name": "name"
    }]
```

Login your server account over ssh by the vscode terminal. Then you can edit and run your code on remote server.

Comment: where should I save this file ?

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling it and re-enabling it. It works for me.

I was able to log in via putty and ssh from terminal, so it wasn't that. It's just the configuration gets hung up or something.