# VSCODE remote editing, download-on-open option?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am mostly editing files remotely in VSCode, and have tried several sftp extensions.  ftp-sync has been the best so far, but there is one nagging problem that hopefully someone has solved: Upload-on-save is great and works perfectly, but I'd like to Download-on-open also (with bonus points for warning if the file is different).  I sometimes edit the remote files on the remote server, and because there's no check in vscode on open, it's easy to lose those changes.  Anyone run into this and have suggestions for a different extension that works this way?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/55960068/6309, with SSH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A recent release on March 19th of https://github.com/liximomo/vscode-sftp has added support for this functionality with downloadOnOpen.  It works perfectly for my use case (if there's an updated version of the file on the server, download and use that). The UX is a little rough still, but will surely improve over time.

If you're using git locally, there's very little chance of losing local changes, so this works perfectly for the case where you want to edit and manage files locally, but stay in sync per-file with a remote ssh/sftp server.

Answer (score 2):

Look into the [Remote VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rafaelmaiolla.remote-vscode) plugin. It doesn't do FTP-like navigation, but if you use SSH, you can tunnel an editing session over the connection into VSCode pretty easily. It felt a little wonky at first, but I use this plugin constantly. As I work across a fleet of a few hundred servers, this option made a lot more sense than trying to set up some of those "deploy" plugins for each host.

Comment: Thanks that's close, but I'm working with other people's servers (some AIX or more exotic), so installing anything server side like rmate can be difficult to get approval for.  There's a recent release of vscode-sftp that has some support for downloadOnOpen which is really what I'm looking for.  Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

Check This Extension on VSCode.Its really awesome.

[Remote WorkSpace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mkloubert.vscode-remote-workspace)