# VS Code Remote SSH Connection not working

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, remote-access

Im trying to setup vscode with the remote developement extensions on a second pc. While it works on my main one it doesnt on the second one. Tried reinstalling vscode, extensions and using older versions but nothing works.

When trying to connect it cancels after chosing the os. So I cant even type in the password.
I set it up in the exact same way as with the other pc.

Any ideas?

````
[20:32:53.595] remote-ssh@0.55.0
[20:32:53.595] win32 x64
[20:32:53.596] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+ssh.blabla", attempt 1
[20:32:53.597] SSH Resolver called for host: ssh.blabla
[20:32:53.597] Setting up SSH remote "ssh.blabla"
[20:32:53.610] Using commit id "58bb7b2331731bf72587010e943852e13e6fd3cf" and quality "stable" for server
[20:32:53.612] Install and start server if needed
[20:32:54.639] Checking ssh with "ssh -V"
[20:32:54.686] > OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5

[20:32:54.691] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 52819 ssh.blabla bash
[20:32:54.694] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[20:32:54.758] >
]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[20:32:54.758] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[20:32:54.785] >
[20:32:55.045] > root@blabla's password: 
[20:32:55.045] Showing password prompt
[20:32:57.596] "install" terminal command done
[20:32:57.597] Install terminal quit with output: root@blabla's password: 
[20:32:57.597] Received install output: root@blabla's password: 
[20:32:57.598] Stopped parsing output early. Remaining text: root@blabla's password:
[20:32:57.598] Failed to parse remote port from server output
[20:32:57.603] Resolver error: Error: 
    at Function.Create (c:\Users\Manuel.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.55.0\out\extension.js:1:130564)
    at Object.t.handleInstallOutput (c:\Users\Manuel.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.55.0\out\extension.js:1:127671)
    at I (c:\Users\Manuel.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.55.0\out\extension.js:127:106775)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
    at async c:\Users\Manuel.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.55.0\out\extension.js:127:104774
    at async Object.t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\Manuel.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.55.0\out\extension.js:127:109845)
    at async Object.t.resolve (c:\Users\Manuel.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.55.0\out\extension.js:127:107960)
    at async c:\Users\Manuel.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.55.0\out\extension.js:127:141955
[20:32:57.606] ------




[20:32:59.376] Password dialog canceled
[20:32:59.376] "install" terminal command canceled```
````

Comment: For me deleting the Code folder and restarting the VS Code worked.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47689536/how-to-completely-uninstall-vs-code-on-windows

Comment: 2024 February: For errors on old OSes like centos7 / RHEL 7.x, see [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/203375) which started with vscode v1.86

Answer (score 93):

Depending on the system you are in, when you first try to connect, a vscode-server will be set up and configured on your server.

In linux that can be in `/Home/<user>/.vscode-server`

If you are on windows, check what that is.

The first solution is to try the extension command: `Remote-SSH: kill VS Code Server on Host`

Open the command pallet (`CTRL + SHIFT + P` or `COMMAND + SHIFT + P` (mac) ).

And type `Remote kill` :

[image]

Then try to connect again! (That will kill the server on the host! Which will make it start again on the next try)

If that doesn't work, and things are still failing:

### Delete, rm

Then a good solution that can work is: to connect to your server through terminal (vscode terminal, gnome-terminal, whatever). Then go and remove `/Home/<user>/.vscode-server`

Try to connect after that. At the attempt the server will be re-installed completely anew, chances are it will work. (I did that and it worked for me, so whatever that was going wrong on the vscode-server: just start all over)

But again: you will lose things, config, meta data, etc. (because you start anew).

### Update:

As stated by @natevw in the comments:

> I found that removing only the `.vscode-server/bin` subfolder helped straighten things out and afaict kept my data/settings.

Removing only `vscode-server/bin` seems to work well, and the config, metadata, etc. remains untouched.

Comment: Hi, how do I open this window where I type remote kill please?

Comment: Hi, It's the command pallet. You can do that with CTRL + SHIFT + P (or COMMAND + SHIFT + P in mac)

Comment: That is really helpful. Been searching the solution for days and glad that I pondered on your solution. But may I know why do we have to kill VS code server?

Comment: I found that removing only the `.vscode-server/bin` subfolder helped straighten things out and afaict kept my data/settings.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that. That's great. I'll add a note to the answer.

Comment: I just wanted to add, that I had the same error, but the remote had no vscode-server installed, but rather I had the sync-setting package sync my settings from another computer and I accidently gave the config the same information as on old one so the setting thought it was the wrong OS.  Renaming the ssh config fixed everything.

Comment: rm /Home/<user>/.vscode-server worked for me. Thanks

Comment: **Solved for me! (on Windows)**

I have 2 remote Windows servers, the 1st one was working and the 2nd one stopped working.
I had the same SSH logs, it seems that VSCode couldn't copy his server to the 2nd server anymore (I don't know why).

I copied the files from the  1st server to the 2nd server: `C:/Users/{myname1}/.vscode-server` from the 1st server to 2nd server `C:/Users/{myname2}/.vscode-server`.

Be sure to use the correct SSH user {myname2} to connect to the server after that.

Answer (score 30):

I downgrade Remote-SSH plugin to 0.51.0, `rm -rf $HOME/.vscode-server` on the remote machine. Connect again, VSCode will download and install a new .vscode-server. Then upgrade Remote-SSH plugin, everything works.

Comment: This worked for me as well.. I was able to ssh through command prompt, delete the .vscode-server file in home and tried ssh through VSCode and it worked... Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks a lot. This saved me a lot of trouble!

Comment: That didnt work for me.

Comment: Worked for me without even downgrading! only removed the dir on the host and tried connecting again.

Answer (score 23):

One way worked for me is, by adding this line in the vscode settings (JSON) file.

`"remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false`

[image: VSCode settings]

Comment: This fixed for me. After the first connection I removed this setting and it kept working

Comment: For me it leads to: Received install output: /bin/sh: 1: ssh: not found

Comment: This one has been the closest to a full success among everything else I tried. Thank you

Comment: I also had to Add / Modify the following line for it to fix the problem: `"remote.SSH.useExecServer": false`

Answer (score 16):

I met the same problem. After I did these steps, it works:

on the remote server:

```
rm -rf ~/.vscode-server  
rm -rf ~/.vscode
```

On the local VS code:

```
reinstall remote-ssh
```

Answer (score 7):

In case all the above fails, here's how I fixed my issue.

First, I was able to SSH into my remote server (Ubuntu 22.04, Raspberry Pi 4, arm64) using a simple bash terminal. So I logged in using my terminal (macOS), and I went to

```
cd $HOME/.vscode-server/bin/WHATEVER-HASH-YOU-HAVE/
```

In this directory, there is a file named `server.sh`. I tried running this script, and I got the following error:

```
./node: error while loading shared libraries: libatomic.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The issue was clear: there was a missing shared library on my system. Either Node.js now requires that or the new version of the SSH-Remote extension; I don't know. I did not spent the time to dig into those specifics.

But to fix that, I simply did:

```sh
sudo apt-get install libatomic1
```

That installed the missing shared library.

After that, I delete `$HOME/.vscode-server`:

```sh
rm -rf $HOME/.vscode-server
```

and tried again connecting using VSCode. It worked!

Hope this can help someone like me, for whom all other options failed.

Answer (score 5):

**Issue**: while trying to ssh connect to Linux(remote machine) using vscode.

**Solution**: *remove/delete the bin folder inside .vscode-server and then reconnect to the remote machine*

## In remote server:

```
remote_name:~$ rm -rf ~/.vscode-server/bin

*reconnect to remote machine*
```

Answer (score 4):

To add what @cagriyonca mentioned, delete the ip that is in the file located in Windows in:

```
C:\Users\<YourUsername>\.ssh\known_hosts
```

This worked for me

Comment: Thank you sir! I banged my head for hours for not being able to connect to a host I previously connected.

Comment: I was getting the following errors prior to being prompted for ssh key (or password). Removing `known_hosts` did the trick. "getsockname failed: bad file descriptor" "got some output, clearing connection timeout" "channel_send_open: channel 2: unexpected internal error" "the process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe"

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that my `fish` was a obstacle for vscode server.

Then I tried

```sh
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

And works fine.

Comment: Thank you sir <3 That was also my issue it seems!

Comment: Is there a way to use ssh with fish as a default shell?

Answer (score 1):

I tried below steps in host terminal and issue was resolved.

```
cd .vscode-server/bin/

cd b3e4e68a0bc097f0ae7907b217c1119af9e03435/ (this folder name can be different for you)

tar -zxvf vscode-server.tar.gz

mv vscode-server-linux-x64/* .

rm -rf vscode-server-linux-x64/ vscode-server.tar.gz

touch 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same issue. Nothing seemed to work (uninstall extension, uninstall VSCode, delete a bunch of cache folders, etc). SSH through terminal was working, but not on VSCode.

After working a bit on the terminal I got an error for no empty space, so deleting a bunch of files on the server was the solution for me, it was nothing related to VSCode.

Answer (score 1):

On the remote server, you run this command below. After that, the VScode window should be reloaded and you connect to the remote via SSH again.

```
rm -rf $HOME/.vscode-server
```

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled upon this situation today. **Switching to Pre-Release Version** for my Remote-SSH extension worked.

Answer (score 1):

1. Kill and uninstall the VS Code Server on your remote host. This is done via **`Strg + Shift + P`**, then selecting "Remote-SSH: Kill VS Code Server on Host", "**`Uninstall VS Code Server from Host`**".
2. Clear your SSH configuration: **`Strg + Shift + P`** + **`Remote-SSH: Open SSH Configuration File`**.
3. In your User Settings in the Extensions section, enable the option **`Remote.SSH: Lockfiles In Tmp`**

Answer (score 0):

I worked adding `\\` in the path of the `.config`

I share the steps

- Go to .config settings
  [image]
- select configuration
  [image]
- add double `\\`

  [image]

Comment: @Yatin Not anymore for what person? I still can not see the question.

Comment: The answer doesn't have formatting issues anymore..

Answer (score 0):

Just deleted old host information from ssh settings file and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced this issue when I tried to connect to a Linux server from a windows laptop.
It was using the wrong fingerprint.
It worked for me after removing the line related to that server from $HOME/.ssh/known_hosts

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, it got fixed when I updated the path of the IdentityFile from 'ssh_key' to '~/.ssh/ssh_key' (the entire path I mean) so that the VS code could recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

Restart remote machine worked for me (after trying all the previous answers with no luck).

Answer (score 0):

Giving you the oldest trick of the book:

```
restart
```

It worked for me and I laughed hysterically for exactly 57 seconds. Happy reconnecting to the server my dear Coder!

Comment: "Restart" what? Is it a command? Is it a human action? What if I cannot simply "restart" the SSH server? Can you please update your solution and be mindful of adding some more details? Thanks.

Comment: @absay on terminal type: restart or just restart manually. I know you can't "restart" the SSH server, but rebooting my own machine miraculously helped me that time. I had tried all of the other solutions on the internet for this issue, but nothing else had fixed it. or could have been, with other solutions, you gotta reboot your machine as well. I don't know how it helped, but it did.

Answer (score 0):

I could not connect to the server, my issue was the remote server was full

check with the command `df -h` if the disk is full !

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to remove `arm_64bit=1` from `config.txt` (`/boot/config.txt`).

Answer (score 0):

I had previously tried to get vs code working on the remote machine.
I deleted both the home/.vscode-server AND the .vscode directories.  These dirs were NOT deleted by uninstalling vs code on the remote machine

This also might help.  I set the debug level by adding "logLevel  DEBUG3" on the  .ssh config file in VSCode

The logs are were very hard for me to find and are not named as the terminal output says they are (long hex string .log).  I finally found it them in C:\Users<user>\AppData\Roaming\Code\logs   they can be found by using command Developer:Open logs folder.  There you will find subfolders named windowx.  Under the window where the error occurred (you just have to look in by time) find exthot/output_logging_xxxxx/remote - ssh.log.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Rocky9 minimal install) the "tar" utility was not installed.
After I installed tar (dnf install tar) it starts working.
The error message produces by installer is quite misleading.

Answer (score 0):

For me, turned out it was a issue with the .pem file

After testing all solutions above, I figured out the .shh/config file was using IdentityFile without the complete path. So, I added the complete path on the config file such as:

```
Host your-alias
  HostName ec2-xx-yy-zz.compute-1.amazonaws.com
  IdentityFile C:\Users\your-user\folder\ec2-pem-file.pem
  User ubuntu
```

When prompting the error "Could not establish connection", I checked on the log (VS Code Output tab) the "no such identity" message just before the "[20:32:57.603] Resolver error: Error: " message.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers may not be sufficient if your SSH host server lacks SSD capacity.

If you have tried all the above solutions and they have not worked for you, check if your host server has enough capacity to accommodate `./vscode-server`. In my case, after deleting large files from my server, I was able to effectively use SSH.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that ~/.bashrc on my remote server contained an erroneous 'exit' that was supposed to execute only during non-interactive sessions, to avoid terminal output during scp commands.

I had implemented that solution successfully on another server though.  Not sure why it broke the second one. Both are CentOS 7, but different patch levels.

Removed the exit statement and now remote-ssh works great.

```
# .bashrc
# ...
if [[ $- == *i* ]]
then
    :
else
    exit # <--- Culprit
fi
# Other stuff useful only for interactive shells.
```

I had found this solution here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26676/how-to-check-if-a-shell-is-login-interactive-batch but now starting to doubt it?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it seems that the `~` directory is full so that I cannot connect through vscode but can connect through CLI. So I recommend to change the server install path according to [How to change vscode-server directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62613523/how-to-change-vscode-server-directory).

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple causes for this. In my case TCP Forwarding was disable in remote Rocky Linux 8 SSH Host.

debug1: server_request_direct_tcpip: originator 127.0.0.1 port 59196, target 127.0.0.1 port 41455
refused local port forward: originator 127.0.0.1 port 59196, target 127.0.0.1 port 41455

Changing AllowTcpForwarding no to yes in /etc/ssh/sshd_config and restart sshd resolve the problem.

-Sachin

Answer (score 0):

The problem I encountered is that vscode remote ssh requires repeatedly entering the password, but it cannot connect correctly.

The solution is to remove the ssh prefix from the entered ssh address.
e.g.

> ssh user00@192.168.140.55  --error

> user00@192.168.140.55    --ok

Answer (score -1):

In my situation i tried all other answers that were given in this thread, None worked. I could manually ssh through the command line but I could not connect through *Connect to Host...* option.

My **solution** was to connect to the VPN of my company (since this is a work related topic)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34481067)

Answer (score -2):

Here is an alternative for Remote SSH, pls check my answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68046111/13089935

TLDR:

We can use a web-based VS Code that is installed on the server directly.