# I cannot find vscode-server for VS code

Tags: vscode-server

I am referring to the question from [VS Code Remote SSH Connection not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64034813/23914212) as my VS code does not connect to host. There one suggestion is to delete the bin folder in vscode-server. Unfortunately, I am unable to find it anywhere on my computer. Is there any specific file within the VS code window itself where I could perhaps find the pwd to the folder?

I tried  Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq ".vscode-server" } in VS code and dir /s /b .vscode-server in my command prompt both gave me nothing.